# How can I implement a Grid with elements in C# for Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the XAML that I have:

```
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,1,*"
              ColumnSpacing="0">
   <t:PopupCancelButton Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding CancelCmd}"/>
   <t:PopupVertical Grid.Column="1" />
   <t:PopupOKButton IsEnabled="{Binding OKEnabled}" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding OKCmd}" />
</Grid>
```

I can set up the elements like this:

```
var cancel = new PopupCancelButton();
cancel.SetBinding(PopupCancelButton.CommandProperty, "CancelCmd");
var ok = new PopupCancelButton();
ok.SetBinding(PopupCancelButton.CommandProperty, "OKCmd");
ok.SetBinding(PopupCancelButton.IsEnabledProperty, "OKEnabled");
```

But I am having a problem adding these to a Grid:

```
var grid = new Grid();
{
   cancel,
   new PopupVertical(),
   ok
}
```

Can someone give me advice on how I can do this and also how I can set the column definitions and the sizes for the Grid in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with:

```
grid.Children.Add(cancel);
grid.Children.Add(new PopupVertical());
grid.Children.Add(ok);
```

Please take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=net-5.0